# JSF 2.1 Primefaces 5.2 Datatable edit null pointer exception

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, jboss

I'm Using JSF 2.1 with JBOSS eap6.1 Primefaces 5.2

I wanted to make a website allowing the user to enter items and add them to a table. After I exceeded 200 items in the table, the performance is not good anymore, because with each addition I have to update the table to see the recent added item. But now I got a NullPointerException while updating the table after reaching 230 ROWS, till 229 rows it's working fine:

```
09:29:25,475 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/JETMealOrder].[Faces Servlet]] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8088-6) JBWEB000236: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.createPartialResponseWriter(PartialViewContextImpl.java:443) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19-redhat-1]
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.access$300(PartialViewContextImpl.java:72) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19-redhat-1]
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$DelayedInitPartialResponseWriter.getWrapped(PartialViewContextImpl.java:577) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19-redhat-1]
    at javax.faces.context.PartialResponseWriter.startDocument(PartialResponseWriter.java:115) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialResponseWriter.startDocument(PrimePartialResponseWriter.java:146) [primefaces-5.2.jar:5.2]
    at com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.handlePartialResponseError(AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.java:199) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19-redhat-1]
    at com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.handle(AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.java:124) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19-redhat-1]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:119) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19-redhat-1]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:116) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19-redhat-1]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19-redhat-1]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:100) [primefaces-5.2.jar:5.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:336) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:920) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
```

**Code:**

```html
<p:dataTable tableStyle="width:auto" id="items" var="p"
             widgetVar="itemstbl" value="#{viewOrder.order.opNonMenus}"
             editMode="cell" editable="#{viewOrder.readonly==false}"
             rowKey="#{p.serial}" draggableRows="#{viewOrder.readonly==false}"
             sortBy="#{p.serial}">
    <p:ajax event="rowReorder" update="form:items"
            listener="#{viewOrder.onRowReorder}" />
    <f:facet name="header">Meal Order Details</f:facet>
    <p:column headerText="S.No." style="width:25px">
        <h:outputText value="#{p.serial}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Item Code">
        <p:cellEditor>
            <f:facet name="output">
                <h:outputText value="#{(p.withCode==1)? p.itemCode : '@FLP'}" />
            </f:facet>
            <f:facet name="input">
                <p:inputText value="#{p.itemCode}" id="code"
                             onblur="value = value.toUpperCase()">
                    <p:ajax event="blur" update="items"
                            listener="#{viewOrder.validateNonMenu(p)}" />
                </p:inputText>
            </f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Item Description">
        <p:cellEditor>
            <f:facet name="output">
                <h:outputText id="qdesc" value="#{p.itemDesc}" />
            </f:facet>
            <f:facet name="input">
                <p:inputTextarea value="#{p.itemDesc}" autoResize="true"
                                 cols="30" placeholder="Item Description" rows="1" />
            </f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Class">
        <p:cellEditor>
            <f:facet name="output">
                <h:outputText id="qclass" value="#{p.classCode.toUpperCase()}" />
            </f:facet>
            <f:facet name="input">
                <p:inputText value="#{p.classCode}"
                             onblur="value = value.toUpperCase()" />
            </f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="UOM">
        <p:cellEditor>
            <f:facet name="output">
                <h:outputText id="quom" value="#{p.uom}" />
            </f:facet>
            <f:facet name="input">
                <p:inputText value="#{p.uom}"
                             onblur="value = value.toUpperCase()">
                    <p:ajax event="blur" update="form:items:0:code" />
                </p:inputText>
            </f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Group">
        <p:cellEditor>
            <f:facet name="output">
                <h:outputText id="qgrp" value="#{p.groupClass}" />
            </f:facet>
            <f:facet name="input">
                <p:autoComplete forceSelection="false" var="group"
                                itemLabel="#{group}" itemValue="#{group}"
                                value="#{p.groupClass}"
                                completeMethod="#{viewOrder.completeQqcGroup}">
                    <f:facet name="itemtip">
                        <h:outputText value="#{group}" />
                    </f:facet>
                </p:autoComplete>
            </f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Item Cost">
        <p:cellEditor>
            <f:facet name="output">
                <h:outputText value="#{p.purCost}" />
            </f:facet>
            <f:facet name="input">
                <p:inputText readonly="#{p.withCode==1}"
                             onkeypress="var key = window.event ? event.keyCode : event.which; if (event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 37 || event.keyCode == 39) return true; else if (key & lt; 48 || key & gt; 57) return false;"
                             value="#{p.purCost}" />
            </f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Quantity">
        <p:cellEditor>
            <f:facet name="output">
                <h:outputText value="#{p.qtyItem}" />
            </f:facet>
            <f:facet name="input">
                <p:inputText
                    onkeypress="var key = window.event ? event.keyCode : event.which; if (event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 37 || event.keyCode == 39) return true; else if (key & lt; 48 || key & gt; 57) return false;"
                    value="#{p.qtyItem}" />
            </f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>
    </p:column>
    <p:column style="width:32px;text-align: center"
              headerText="Image">
        <p:commandButton update="form:cpsDetail"
                         oncomplete="PF('cpsinfo').show()" icon="ui-icon-image"
                         title="View Image">
            <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{p}"
                                         target="#{viewOrder.selectedItem}" />
        </p:commandButton>
    </p:column>
    <p:column style="width:32px;text-align: center"
              headerText="Replace">
        <p:commandButton rendered="#{viewOrder.readonly==false}"
                         update="form:rrepotbl" icon="ui-icon-refresh"
                         widgetVar="rplbtn" title="Replace Item"
                         oncomplete="PF('rdlg').show();">
            <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{p}"
                                         target="#{viewOrder.replaceItem}" />
        </p:commandButton>
    </p:column>
    <p:column style="width:32px;text-align: center"
              headerText="Replace by Menu">
        <p:commandButton rendered="#{viewOrder.readonly==false}"
                         update="form:rMrepotbl" icon="ui-icon-refresh"
                         widgetVar="rplbtn" title="Replace Item"
                         oncomplete="PF('rMdlg').show();">
            <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{p}"
                                         target="#{viewOrder.replaceItem}" />
        </p:commandButton>
    </p:column>
    <p:column style="width:32px;text-align: center"
              headerText="Delete">
        <p:commandButton rendered="#{viewOrder.readonly==false}"
                         update="form:items" action="#{viewOrder.delete}"
                         icon="ui-icon-close" title="Delete Item">
            <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{p}"
                                         target="#{viewOrder.selectedItem}" />
        </p:commandButton>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

```
public void addNewItem() {
        OpNonMenu item = new OpNonMenu();
        item.setDblDate(order.getDblDate());
        item.setFlightNoD(order.getFltNoD());
        item.setCustomerCode(cust.getCode());
        item.setMainSbdCode(order.getMainSbdCode());
        item.setSalesEditBy(log.getUserId());
        item.setSalesEditDate(order.getEditDate());

        item.setSerial(order.getOpNonMenus().size() + 1);
        item.setEditBy(order.getEditBy());
        item.setEditDate(order.getEditDate());
        item.setClassCode("");
        item.setWithCode(0);
        item.setItemCode("@FLP");
        item.setItemType("S");
        order.addOpNonMenu(item);
    }
```

Comment: can you post your ManagedBean and your function to insert items?

Comment: put that function between try{}catch(Exception e){} and show us the error

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved the issue of null pointer exception by increase the max count property in standalone.xml in JBOSS server

```
 <system-properties>
        <property name="org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters.MAX_COUNT" value="10000"/>
</system-properties>
```

but still the performance getting worse after no of rows increase.